# managing array of structures vb.net

Tags: winforms, arrays, structure

i need to work with `100,000` list of data. sometimes need to remove an item close to the end or middle.

```
Structure Proxy
    Dim ID as Integer
    Dim Server As String
    Dim Port As Integer
End Structure

dim oProxy(100,000) as Proxy
```

what is the best way to add, delete from any location within the arrays of structures structure

as you know looping to to remove from the middle or end can be a pain. should i use `list<>` instead?

EDIT

I would like to remove an item by ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how do you find the item you want to remove? do you have its index available
or do you remove it after server and port and need to search it?

because the later i would use a hashed option. Dictionary in .net http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx
in that case finding the item you want to remove is your bigest concern.

other wise a List<> would be fine..... dont use arrays because of 100 000 items ;D